# Many to many in drupal 8

Tags: entities

I have googled and read many posts on entity reference, taxonomy etc...

Here is the problem:

I have a procedures entity and sequences. Procedures can have any number of sequences. The same sequence may belong to many procedures.

The key difference for me is I need the order of the sequences to be specific per procedure.

I assume a custom taxonomy with an 'offset' field added would be sufficient to address this requirement?

Suggestions?

Comment: `I have a procedures entity and sequences` you mean content types?

Comment: is sequences a taxonomy vocabulary?

Comment: the word [entity is not helpful here, it can mean many things](https://drupalize.me/videos/what-are-drupal-entities?p=1174)... plz be more specific. thx!